# show Diff value of node in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working with a series of  xml like this

---

```
    <jobpost id='01'>
<candidate id='0000079'>
    <firstName>AAAA</firstName>
    <lastName>BBBB</lastName>
    <age>32</age>
    <salaryoff>37000</salaryoff>
    <exp>C</exp>
    <cat>
        <award>5</award>
        <hst>5</hst>
        <previous>7</previous>
        <flex>3</flex>
        <travel>4</travel>
    </cat>
</candidate>
<candidate id='0000072'>
    <firstName>CCCCC</firstName>
    <lastName>DDDDD</lastName>
    <age>37</age>
    <salaryoff>40000</salaryoff>
    <exp>B</exp>
    <cat>
        <award>6</award>
        <hst>5</hst>
        <previous>6</previous>
        <flex>2</flex>
        <travel>3</travel>
    </cat>
</candidate>
```

---

```
    <jobpost id='01'>
   <candidate id='0000072'>
    <firstName>CCCCC</firstName>
    <lastName>DDDDD</lastName>
    <age>38</age>
    <salaryoff>40000</salaryoff>
    <exp>A</exp>
    <cat>
        <award>6</award>
        <hst>5</hst>
        <previous>6</previous>
        <flex>2</flex>
        <travel>0</travel>
    </cat>
</candidate>
<candidate id='0000103'>
    <firstName>KKKKK</firstName>
    <lastName>JJJJJ</lastName>
    <age>21</age>
    <salaryoff>29000</salaryoff>
    <exp>D</exp>
    <cat>
        <award>2</award>
        <hst>5</hst>
        <previous>6</previous>
        <flex>6</flex>
        <travel>7</travel>
    </cat>
</candidate>
```

and I'm tryin to get something like this

```
AAAA    BBBB    32     C       5   5   7   3   4       37000
CCCCC   DDDDD   38(1)  A(+1)   6   5   6   2   0(-3)   40000
KKKKK   JJJJJ   21     D       2   5   6   6   7       21000
```

and I was looking for a solution to get the difference of the value of the node.
I was working something with loop with descendant, node and navigation.
I was wondering if there is a way more simple or some direct tool to reach the goal 
thx for any suggestion.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: is it all about compare two XMLS? well... you have some formatted output, but in general wouldn't be a dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713649/linq-comparing-2-xml-files-and-outputting-to-xml-the-differences/19713723#19713723

Comment: @JohnSaunders thx! and sorry  :-)

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I was wondering if there was some "direct" way to get that result. The nested "cat" node maybe fool me and convince me it was more complicated. Thx for your suggestion. I'll keep tryin.